# Quadratic form defined by a permutation of projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, quadratic-forms

Let $M$ be a projection matrix. We know that
$$
v'Mv=(Mv)'(Mv)=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}v_iM_{ij}v_j\leq \sum^n_{i=1}v_i^2
$$
where $v$ is a column vector with dimension compatible to $M$.

Can we conclcude the same thing with following?
$$
v'M'PMv=(Mv)'(PMv)=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}v_i[\sum_{k}M_{ik}(PM)_{kj}]v_j\leq \sum^n_{i=1}v_i^2
$$
where $P$ is a permutation matrix.

If the answer is no, can we put addition restriction on $P$ to make it true? For example, if
$$
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0&\vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \ddots &\vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0&1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: The example $P$ that you give is not a permutation matrix

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you're looking for holds as a consequence of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. I will use $\|x\|$ to refer to the norm $\|x\| = \sqrt{x'x}$. We note that $\|Px\| = \|x\|$ for all $x$. Thus, we can apply the CS inequality to get
$$
v'M'PMv = (Mv)'(PMv) \leq \|Mv\| \cdot \|PMv\| = \|Mv\|^2 \leq \|v\|^2.
$$